# insert view in front of UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone

I use the codes below to insert view in front of UIImagePickerContrller

```
[self.view insertSubview:myFrontView atIndex:1000];
```

It worked.

But if the ViewController relates to the 'self' was presented by UINavigationController,

myFronView will display behind UIImagePickerController rather than display in front of it.

Is there anyone met the same problem?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add your subview to the UIImagePickerController's view rather than to the view of the view controller on top of the navigation stack since your controller's view is not going to be visible when the UIImagePickerController's view is displayed.

However sticking your own subviews into a view hierarchy managed by a controller you did not write (like UIImagePickerController) might cause problems. If at all possible you should be using UIImagePickerController's [cameraOverlayView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) property to display your custom view in a supported way.