# Show a view in front of the imagePicker

Tags: swift, animation, view, uiimagepickercontroller

In my application the user can either open the camera roll to select a picture or open the camera to take directly one by himself.

In both cases, the picture selected/taken will also be saved locally for further reference.

The downside is that the saving operation usually freeze the screen until it is finished.

I found an animation [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453812/create-spinning-circle-loading-animation) and I want to display it in front of the `imagePickerController` but I can't manage to do so.

```
class SinglePageViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate {

    var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView?

    lazy var showCameraImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController = {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        return imagePicker
    }()

    lazy var showPhotoImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController = {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        return imagePicker
    }()

    @IBOutlet weak var photoButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func onPhotoButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.present(self.showCameraImagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var galleryButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func onGalleryButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.present(self.showPhotoImagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {

        //start animation
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

        spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: screenSize.width / 2 - 150, y: screenSize.height / 2 - 150, width: 300, height: 300))
        spinner?.isHidden = false
        spinner?.startAnimating()
        spinner?.color = UIColor.red

        switch picker {
        case showCameraImagePickerController:
            // snap pic, save to doc, save to album

            self.showCameraImagePickerController.view.addSubview(spinner!)

            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false, block: { _ in

                let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

                if self.saveImage(imageName: "\(self.titleLabel.text!).png", image: image) {
                    // additionally save to photo album
                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

                    print("saved \(self.titleLabel.text!).png")

                    self.imageView.image = image
                }
            })

        case showPhotoImagePickerController:
            //switch pic, save to doc. no album

            self.showPhotoImagePickerController.view.addSubview(spinner!)

            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false, block: { _ in

                let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

                if self.saveImage(imageName: "\(self.titleLabel.text!).png", image: image) {

                    print("saved new \(self.titleLabel.text!).png")

                    self.imageView.image = image

                    self.spinner?.stopAnimating()
                    self.spinner?.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.spinner = nil

                    self.showPhotoImagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    self.spinner?.stopAnimating()
                    self.spinner?.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.spinner = nil

                    self.showPhotoImagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })

        default:
            return
        }

    }

    @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {

        spinner?.stopAnimating()
        spinner?.removeFromSuperview()
        spinner = nil

        self.showCameraImagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func saveImage(imageName: String, image: UIImage?) -> Bool {

        //create an instance of the FileManager
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        //get the image path
        let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(imgDir + imageName)
        print(imagePath)

        //get the image we took with camera
        let image = rotateImage(image: image!)

        //get the PNG data for this image
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

        //store it in the document directory
        if fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath as String, contents: data, attributes: nil) {
            newItem?.image = true

            return true
        } else {
            print("error while saving")
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see I tried playing with `bringSubView(toFront:)` and also with the `zPosition` but with no results.

following [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582069/insert-view-in-front-of-uiimagepickercontroller) I looked into the documentation for [cameraOverlayView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619113-cameraoverlayview) but it says that it only works when the imagePicker is presented in camera mode, which doesn't cover the case when I open the photo library

I also recently tried to use a workaround, meaning that I dismiss the imagePickerController as soon as possible and update the image afterwards, but that is not optimal anymore because of some changes in the structure of app.

EDIT

to make myself clearer I'll state again what I need: show the spinner animation **in front** of the imagePicker, as soon as I tap a photo to choose it, and until I finish saving, then dismiss the imagePicker.
I **do not** want to first dismiss the picker and then save while showing the spinner in the main view.

EDIT2
updated the code with the new one from the answer. only problem is that if I don't put a timer the spinner shows itself only at the end of the saving process for a brief moment (checked with breakpoints).
This results in no animation during the couple of seconds of saving process and just a brief apparition of the spinner at the end before dismissing the imagePicker.
Just putting a 0.1sec delay triggers the spinner immediately and I get the expected behaviour (animation while saving).
No idea why

Comment: Code looks fine. Try setting `backgroundColor` for `spinnerView` and check where it goes in `DebugViewHierarchy`.

Comment: I was able to verify that `spinnerView` gets created. if I don't remove it at successful save, when the imagePicker closes I can see it . It is only a matter of moving it in front

Comment: Hi @Kamran sorry to bother you but do you have any idea on how to solve my problem? I would offer a bounty but I have too few points..

Comment: let me try. The spinner class is same as in the other question?

Comment: I actually changed it to a simpler `mySpinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: screenSize.width/2 - 50, y: screenSize.height/2 - 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        mySpinner?.isHidden = false
        mySpinner?.startAnimating()
        mySpinner?.color = UIColor.black
        self.view.addSubview(mySpinner!)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see a complete example where spinner will show while the image is being saved and once finishes saving spinner will be removed.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    /// Image picker controller
    lazy var imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController  = {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        return imagePicker
    }()

    var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView?

    @IBAction func imagePickerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.present(self.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: ImagePicker Delegate to get the image picked by the user
extension ViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        //start animation
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: screenSize.width/2 - 50, y: screenSize.height/2 - 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        spinner?.isHidden = false
        spinner?.startAnimating()
        spinner?.color = UIColor.black
        self.imagePickerController.view.addSubview(spinner!)

        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

    }

    @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {

        spinner?.stopAnimating()
        spinner?.removeFromSuperview()
        spinner  = nil

        self.imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        if  error == nil {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried incorporating some of your code but now I cannot even see the spinner in the view hierarchy anymore. Why do you do this `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.navigationController?.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil) }` ? I simply present it like this `@IBAction func onGalleryButton(_ sender: Any) {  showImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController() showImagePickerController.delegate = self showImagePickerController.allowsEditing = false showImagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary present(showImagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)}`

Comment: @MaX Although this code works fine but you are still facing the issue so it would be better if you can share your code to figure out the issue. You can share the code specific to only this issue.

Comment: I edited my code. If I don't remove the spinner from the superView I can see it after the `imagePickerController` disappears. but not while saving. (btw thanks for the constant help !)

Comment: So it means it is not taking a noticeable time to save the image. Remember you are dismissing imagePickerController with animation so it also takes some time and if the image is saved in that time, spinner will be removed also and you will not see any spinner. May be you can try put this line at the top of the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` without animation like this `picker.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)` before adding the spinner to the view. This way you might see the spinner.

Comment: I thought so as well , but if instead of picking a picture form the album I take a picture with the camera and save it , it freezes a bit and it’s very noticeable ! It’s also impossible to see it is in the view hierarchy because if I put a breakpoint after adding the spinner as a child view , when I click the button to show the view hierarchy it closes the imagepicker anyways !

Comment: Ok sorry for the delay, I tried your code in a completely new app and I think I wasn't able to properly explain myself. What I want to achieve is being able to see the spinner **in front** of the photo album, as soon as I tap onto a picture to choose it , until it finishes saving it. What your code does is first dismissing the imagePicker and then saving while showing the spinner. As a try I put the saving code before the dismiss, and wrapped everything in a timer for 5 seconds. And the spinner was not visible until the dismissal of the imagePicker.

Comment: @MaX After getting the above clarification, i updated the answer. Try now and you should see spinner in front of the Photo library. Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you! the code works perfectly in the sample app. Unfortunately in my app I have both a `.camera` and `.photoLibrary` imagePicker, and when using the camera one I found a strange behaviour: the spinner does not appear after adding it as a subview of the current imagePickerController but instead only after the saving is finished (resulting in a very brief animation and long freeze time while saving). instead, if I put a timer of 0.1sec the spinner appears immediately, stays there for the whole saving operation and then disappears correctly. Same behaviour for the `.photo` imagePicker. Why?